# ¿Cómo acceder a un objeto de forma inversa? Pongo ejemplo de código para que sea más clara mi pregunta

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Lo voy a poner con un ejemplo práctico:

Tengo una clase principal "VentanaPrincipal"

```
public class VentanaPrincipal{

    private  PanelSecundario panelUno, panelDos, panelTres;

    public VentanaPrincipal(){

        panelUno = new Panel Secundario();
        panelDos = new Panel Secundario();
        ...
    } 
}
```

Tengo otra clase por ahí:

```
public class PanelSecundario(){

    private JButton botonUno;

    public PanelSecundario(){

        boton1 = new JButton("Clickeame");
    }

    public JButton getBotonUno(){

        return this.botonUno;

    }
}
```

Digamos que como todos ya sabemos para acceder a el objeto "botonUno" perteneciente a la clase "PanelSecundario" dentro de la clase principal "ClasePrincipal" hacemos lo siguiente(Sólo un ejemplo sin hacerlo objetivamente):

```
public class VentanaPrincipal{

    private  PanelSecundario panelUno, panelDos, panelTres;

    public VentanaPrincipal(){

        panelUno = new Panel Secundario();
        panelDos = new Panel Secundario();
        ...
    } 

    public void Test(){

        panelUno.getBotonUno(); //Sin ningun objetivo, sólo para poner el ejemplo
    }
}
```

La pregunta es:

Desde la clase principal "VentanaPrincipal" es fácil acceder a otro objeto que contiene otro objeto como el clásico 
    **VentanaPrincipal.PanelSecundario.boton1**

¿CÓMO PUEDO ACCEDER **DESDE** LA CLASE "PanelSecundario" a otro Objeto "PanelSecundario" digamos al objeto "panelDos"? Y hacer operaciones con otro boton de ese panelDos desde mi clase "PanelSecundario"?

Como si desde PanelSecundario hiciera una referencia de este tipo:
**QUIERO ALGO COMO ESTO:**

```
public class PanelSecundario(){

    public PanelSecundario(){
        VentanaPrincipal.panelDos.boton1; // Obvio esto me va a marcar error por que para empezar no esta bien escrito ni tengo un getter, pero digamos que lo represento así para exponer mi idea. Y aparte esto me marca error por que no puedo acceder a un objeto que en jerarquía que esta arriba que es "VentanaPrincipal".
    }

}
```

La subpregunta es: ¿Cómo hago esto que quiero sin una clase anidada, ni pasar "VentanaPrincipal" cómo un parametro al crear un objeto "PanelSecundario" ? ¿Hay una forma de hacerlo limpiamente?

Digo sin más enredos: Como acceder de

VentanaPrincipal.PanelSecundario.boton1

a esto:

VentanaPrincipal<-PanelSecundario<-boton1

ó

boton1.PanelSecundario.VentanaPrincipal

Comment: Omg... a lo mejor no me doy a entender...

Comment: Declara las variables panelUno, panelDos, panelTres, como staticas: `public static PanelSecundario panelUno, panelDos, panelTres;`. Despues unicamente accedes a ellas desde 'VentanaPrincipal.panelDos'. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

A las clases secundarias tendrías que pasarles la referencia de la principal, aunque sospecho que lo que quieres hacer es otra cosa y esta solución que deseas implementar es algo extraña, tendrías que hacer algo como esto

```
public class Panel {

    private Principal p;

    public Panel(Principal p, String value) {
        this.p = p;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void Test() {
        //Accedo al value del Panel 2 desde otro objeto panel pasando por el principal
        System.out.println(p.panel2.getValue());
    }
}


    public class Principal {

        public Panel panel1;
        public Panel panel2;

        public void Test() {
            panel1 = new Panel(this, "uno");
            panel2 = new Panel(this, "dos");
            //llamo al método desde panel 1
            panel1.Test();
        }
    }
```

si me dices para qué quieres hacer algo así tal vez te pueda comentar una mejor solución.

Comment: GRACIAS POR LAS RESPUESTAS, ME HAN GUSTADO, YO YA SABÍA RESOLVERLO DE ESTAS FORMAS PERO QUERÍA SABER SI HABÍA OTRA SOLUCIÓN MÁS DIRECTA DE HACERLO. PERO AL FINAL CREO QUE SON LAS ÚNICAS FORMAS. MUCHAS GRACIAS POR RESPONDERME